# Is it safe to use array_slice to remove scandir dot and dot-dot entries?

Tags: php, scandir

I want to use `array_slice` with `scandir` in my PHP script.

**Normal usage:**

```
<?php

$files = scandir('/path/to/files');

foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        // Do something here...
    }
}
```

**My example:**

```
<?php

$files = array_slice(scandir('/path/to/files'), 2);

foreach($files as $file) {
    // Do something here...
}
```

My doubt is, is it safe or not to use this type of logic ?

Comment: I agree w/@Boann: Clever is often problematic, for multiple reasons. To wit: *"The competent programmer is fully aware of the limited size of his own skull. He therefore approaches his task with full humility, and avoids clever tricks like the plague." — Edsger W. Dijkstra*

Comment: It's strongly not recommended to do that. Just unset the first 2 elements. Or use glob().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely not safe. The following example creates a directory with a file called `!`. When scandir sorts the results, `!` appears before `.` and `..`:

```
mkdir('test');
touch('test/!');
print_r(scandir('test'));
unlink('test/!');
rmdir('test');
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => !
    [1] => .
    [2] => ..
)
```

In general, this will be an issue for all filenames starting with a character which sorts before `.`. That includes some unprintable characters which probably won't exist in real world data, but it also applies to common punctuation including `! # $ % & ( ) + -`.

Even if it worked, I wouldn't recommend it, as using array_slice there makes the intent of the code less clear.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to scan directory by old-school ways, i strongly recommend using of [SPL Directory Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) for such requirement.

Try this:

```
$iterator = new \DirectoryIterator('/path/to/files');
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if($file->isDot()) {
        continue;
    }
    /** Now here you can use lot of SplFileInfo interface methods here */
    // $file->getFilename();
    // $file->isFile();
    // $file->isDir();
    // $file->getSize();
}
```